# Only Match String if Text Does Not Contain Another String

Tags: regex

I have the following use case. I need a Regex pattern to only match a line, if part of the string does not contain a different string. Here is an example:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"/>
```

So here I want to match `android:layout_marginStart="12dp"` so that I can replace with:

```
android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
```

I have worked this one out and I can use the following regex to do it:

Find: `(.*)android:layout_marginStart="(.*)"`
Replace: `$1android:layout_marginStart="$2"\n$1android:layout_marginLeft="$2"`

What I can't do is conditionally match. I do not want to match if this xml object already contains the `android:layout_marginLeft` attribute.

Comment: [Regex is probably not the tool for parsing XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Whilst I understand there is another post asking about checking XML tags, there is also an answer on there https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/507313 that also says using regex for a task like this is fine if its a one time thing which this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regex, if you want to check to make sure a string is not coming up after the part you wish to match, you can use a negative lookahead.

In this example, you want to match something, but only if the string `layout_marginLeft` is not coming up later.  You can do that, but throwing `layout_marginLeft` into a negative lookahead, like this:

```
(?:(?!layout_marginLeft).)*
```

Now, when you combine that with what you actually want to match your regex would look something like this:

```
(android:layout_marginStart="(.*?)")(?:(?!layout_marginLeft).)*(?=/>)
```

And then your replacement string would look like this:

```
\1\n\t\tandroid:layout_marginLeft="\2"
```

So, the replacement stuff works the same way, it's just that you are telling it not to do a replacement on anything that already contains `layout_marginLeft`.

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/09YpwA/1)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Very useful. Is there a way to check both after and before? So not to match:
`android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"`

Comment: [Here you go, brother](https://regex101.com/r/09YpwA/2).  Notice that I added the single-line `s` flag to scan across multiple lines.  This also meant that I had to change the `.` in `"(.*?)"` to not include spaces.  `"([^\s]*?)"`.  Finally, I added the same negative lookahead to the front of the expression.  So now it is in two places.

Comment: Massive thank you for taking the time to fix and explain it. I would never have reached this on my own.

Comment: Sorry, not done yet. When using in Java I get an issue with the `\K` character as it's not supported. Not sure how to resolve. People mention about using capturing groups but can't get these to work.

Comment: are you able to help with the last piece of the puzzle?